# Failed to recognize type of 'location'. It will be treated as String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rubygems, postgis

I'm trying to use the gem `activerecord-postgis-adapter` and when i try to execute this code :

```
require 'active-record' 
require 'pg'
require 'active record-postgis-adapter'

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   record = Place.find(1)
   line = record.location
   puts line.srid
end
```

*srid* is a method of `activerecord-postgis-adapter` and here i'm trying to display the *srid* of my geographical column (location) but the console keeps telling me `Failed to recognize type of 'location'. It will be treated as String.`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably found a solution to my problem, i used **postgresql** as the adapter when connecting to the database, i changed to **postgis** and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

1)Your example has a space in "active record".

Use `require 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'`.

2) As mentioned in other answer: change postgresql for postgis:

In `project_name/config/database.yml`, change the adapter:

```
 default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
```

Becomes

```
 default: &default
  adapter: postgis
```

3) Make sure you have the postgis extension enabled
 `psql -d your_project_name_development -tAc "SELECT 1 from pg_extension where extname='postgis'" | grep -q 1 || \
psql -d your_project_name_development --command="CREATE EXTENSION postgis"`

Also, in my project, I had to **reimport** the data.

Note: you might also need `require 'rgeo-activerecord'` if you're using the RGeo gem.