# Whenever cronjobs doesn't run on staging - but works on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I am facing a very weird scenario.

I am using whenever to run cron jobs in the following way

```
every 1.day, at: '12:30 am' do
     runner 'CronJobs.some_method'
end
```

The error is logged to cron_error.log. Everytime I get this weird error in the log file

```
 unknown OID 705: failed to recognize type of 'user'. It will be treated as String.
```

However, the same cron works fine in the production environment.

I also tried running the method via rails runner and it works fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share whole content of schedule.rb

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163196/failed-to-recognize-type-of-location-it-will-be-treated-as-string

Answer (score 0):

When updating crotab pass environment mode of application

```
 whenever --update-crontab  myapp --set 'environment=stagging'
```

and in schedule.rb add this line

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "#{@pre_set_variables[:environment]}"
```

I hope this helps you !!